# Safari history.db history_tombstones

Tags: safari, browser-history

In Safari, my top hits keeps posting results to a page that I've deleted from my cache quite a long time ago. However, if I open the history.db in `SQlite` I see a number of tables including a "*history_tombstones"*. In this *history_tombstones* I see the link to the site that has been deleted from my cache. What is the table *history_tombstones* used for and how is it populated with entries?

Bonus question is how do I permanently remove these entries? Deleting history.db and *history.db-wal* from my Mac only temporarily deletes these items as the entire DB reappears in minutes. Modifying the table directly doesn't do anything as the cells are overwritten with the original data.

Answer (score -1):

The tombstones are deleted after a full exit from Safari. Just quit Safari and reopen and the tombstones will be gone.

Comment: Hi, these files do not disappear on-quit or machine restart.

Comment: And the tombstones can be backed up to iCloud: https://www.macobserver.com/news/deleted-browser-history-safari-saved-icloud/